# Transform form-style page into multi-level table - Maintain multiple view modes - support Editing and Rearranging of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, backbone.js

I have a form-style page where there are an infinite number of fieldsets nested within each other. An example may be something like this (their actual HTML doesn't really matter but if needed I could provide):

```
FS1 Item1
FS1 Item2
      FS2 Item1
      FS2 Item2
FS1 Item3
FS1 Item4
FS1 Item5
      FS2 Item1
            FS3 Item1
      FS2 Item2
      FS2 Item3
            FS3 Item1
            FS3 Item2
                  FS4 Item1
                  FS4 Item2
            FS3 Item3
      FS2 Item4
FS1 Item6
```

Here's what I need to do:

1. Make it into a table with infinite levels of nested tables within
2. Allow for switching between the "Form View" & the "Table View"
3. Let the user rearrange the table or form as they see fit... In other words, they need to be able to move that `FS3 Item2` to become `FS1 Item2`'s new `FS2 Item3`. And then if the user changes their "View Mode" the change needs to be reflected in the other view.
4. There's already an Edit mode for the "Form View". It needs to work in the "Table View" too, and again, render seamlessly in both view modes.

I'm thinking I can write the code to do the initial render of the "Table View" myself (in fact I already have) but I need something to simplify and tie the view rendering together. The only thing I've found that seems like it might be appropriate is backbone.js and its [View](http://backbonejs.org/#View) component. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I've never used backbone.js before so if the solution involves backbone.js or some other template system I'd really appreciate a little walkthrough!